# How to calculate FFT of real even signal of N points with just N/2 points?

Tags: algorithm, signals, signal-processing, fft, dft

Suppose the given signal is `x = [0 1 2 3 0 3 2 1]`
The FFT of this real even signal is also real even

```
fft(x) = X = [12.0000   -2.8284   -4.0000    2.8284   -4.0000    2.8284   -4.0000   -2.8284];
```

Let `y = x(1:length(x)/2);` i.e. `x = [y 0 fliplr(y(2:end)]` 
I can use `fft(y)` to calculate `X = fft(x)`?

Comment: yes FFT creates mirrored output for any real input its common to use this for speeding up the FFT/iFFT for the first/last  layer of recursion.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is a cosine transform. A regular Fourier transform treats the signal as being circular, so if you only feed it half the signal you will get a very different result. But a cosine transform is the equivalent of a Fourier transformed on a symmetric (by mirroring) signal, so a cosine transform on `y` will do what you want. Just be careful which variant you pick.